# cant get child div hight to auto adjust to parent

Tags: html, css, parent-child

Im trying to get the footer-wrapper to expand in hight to match its children  but im having no luck.  Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

```
 <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <div style="float:left; width:160px">
     <strong>TITLE</strong><br/>
      <a href="#">links</a><br/>
      <a href="#">links</a><br/>
          <a href="#">links</a><br/>
     </div>

        <div style="float:left; width:160px">
     <strong>TITLE</strong><br/>
      <a href="#">links</a><br/>
      <a href="#">links</a><br/>
          <a href="#">links</a><br/>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>


#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent url(../images/bgfooter.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-color: #363732;
  border-top: 5px solid #2c2d29;
  clear: both;/*Clears all columns and sets the footer at the bottom*/
}

/*--Set footer width and center--*/
#footer-wrapper {
  color: #9c9b9a;
  width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  height: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `display: inline-block;` to the #footer

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RE997/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">

<div style="float:left; width:160px">
<strong>TITLE</strong><br/>
<a href="#">links</a><br/>
<a href="#">links</a><br/>
<a href="#">links</a><br/>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:160px">
<strong>TITLE</strong><br/>
<a href="#">links</a><br/>
<a href="#">links</a><br/>
<a href="#">links</a><br/>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<style>

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent url(../images/bgfooter.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-color: #363732;
  border-top: 5px solid #2c2d29;
  clear: both;/*Clears all columns and sets the footer at the bottom*/
}

/*--Set footer width and center--*/
#footer-wrapper {
  color: #9c9b9a;
  width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  height: auto;
 }

 .clear
 {
    clear: both;
 }

</style>
```

please use this code

Comment: As a test, when I add a different background color to footer-wrapper rather than fill to the height of the children it just fills from top down about 10px.

Comment: because you gave padding 20px to footer-wrapper div

Comment: I removed the padding and then the background color doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated css.  I have added a background color to footer wrapper as a test to show height of div but it does not show at all

```
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent url(../images/bgfooter.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-color: #363732;
  border-top: 5px solid #2c2d29;
  clear: both;/*Clears all columns and sets the footer at the bottom*/

}

/*--Set footer width and center--*/
#footer-wrapper {
  color: #9c9b9a;
  width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: auto;
  background-color:#666666;


 }
```